# How can I run a .jar program directly from /bin?

Tags: java, linux, bash, dmenu

Whenever I need to open the logisim-evolution.jar file, I need to type the command:

`java -jar logisim-evolution.jar`

I would like to add an entry for that program in /bin to be able to open it through the dmenu. How can I do that?

Comment: You're better off making a .sh launcher that runs `java -jar logisim-evolution.jar` and put it in `/bin`

Comment: This _can_ be done using `binfmt_misc` (telling the Linux kernel how to recognize a jar as an executable, and spawn the JVM as an interpreter for it, so you can just drop your jar in `/usr/bin` and `chmod +x` it), but as a system-administration task rather than a development one, that's not on-topic here. Consider [unix.se].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're better off making a .sh launcher that runs `java -jar logisim-evolution.jar` and put it in /bin

@Federico klez Culloca

Comment: Mind, ".sh launcher" is misleading -- executables shouldn't have file extensions. The `#!/bin/sh` as the first line is what identifies something as a sh script, not its filename; and as you don't see folks run `pip.py` or `rbenv.rb`, you shouldn't run `myscript.sh` either.